# How to reset the default .EXE icons in Windows XP

Tags: icons, registry, default, exe

I have installed Windows XP after using nlite to remove certain unneeded components. I have tried this before, only now I've selected the registry edit which makes Windows show the default executable icon instead of the program's default one.

This is not related to icon cache as it's a single registry edit which simply disallows programs to use their own icons. Other icons such as My Computer, My documents etc. work, this affects only the .exe files.

How do I undo this? I am pretty sure it involves registry editing, I just don't know what key I am supposed to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution.

First, open `regedit.exe` and then find this key:

```
   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\exefile\DefaultIcon]
```

Change the value of (Default) to %1 and refresh the icon cache. Here's how to do it: [windows icon cache](http://smallvoid.com/article/windows-icon-cache.html)